# bootstrap toggle inside bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I am using a bootstrap toggle styled checkbox (data-toggle="toggle"). This has been working perfectly, no problems. However, if I put this checkbox inside of a bootstrap table (data-toggle="table") the bootstrap toggle checkbox no longer functions properly.
Specifically, the change event fires but the checkbox/button no longer displays the sliding On/Off behavior. I have narrowed this down to happening only when the containing table has the data-toggle="table" element.
Has anyone encountered this and come up with a solution?
Here is my jsFiddle demonstrating this problem:
    [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/melaniedyoung/fwsvrxgo/7/)

html:

```
<div class="cDemo">
<div id="toolbar">
<span>This first table demonstrates the problem</span>
</div>
<table class="table config-table"
   data-toggle="table"
   data-sort-name="Name"
   data-sort-order="asc"
   data-toolbar="#toolbar"
   data-search="true"
   data-search-text=""
   data-pagination="true"
   data-page-size="5"
   data-page-list="[5,10,15]"
   id="configTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
<th data-field="Enable">Enable</th>
<th data-field="Name">Name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>          
  <tr>
  <td>
  <span class="label label-pill pull-left">
    <input id="toggle-trigger" 
          checked="checked"
           data-toggle="toggle"
           class="on-off-btn"
           data-size="mini"
           data-onstyle="danger"
           data-offstyle="default"
           type="checkbox" />
  </span>
</td>
<td>File Name</td>
</table>
</div>
<div id="showResponse1"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.on-off-btn').bootstrapToggle({
  on: 'On',
  off: 'Off'
});

$('.cDemo').on("change","#toggle-trigger",function(e){
    var link = $(e.target);
    $('#showResponse1').html('Toggle: ' + link.prop('checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the plugins that you are using are not designed to handle the rendering of nested plugin elements. Unless you want to change the source you can dynamically add and initialize your toggle switches after the bootstrap-table plugin has been initialized.

Add a `<span class="toggle-placeholder" />` placeholder where you want a toggle switch. Then initialize all of them:

```
$(function() {
    var $checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked "data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="danger" class="on-off-btn" data-size="mini" />'
    $('.toggle-placeholder').html($checkbox);
    $('.toggle-placeholder').find('input[type=checkbox][data-toggle=toggle]')
                            .each(function(){
        $(this).bootstrapToggle();
    });
});
```

As you can see, `$checkbox` is your html for the toggle that you would have had previously in your markup. Then we set the placeholder contents as the `$checkbox` html, then for each `.toggle-placeholder` on the page, we initialize the bootstrap-toggle plugin.

Now this is a rough example where every switch would be the same but you could cutomize each by including your settings in the placeholder. From here the new initializer function could then assign these to the checkbox by reading the placeholder attributes.

Answer (score -1):

First add a class to your input

```
(input class="class-check".....)
```

then add this line:

```
$('.class-check').bootstrapToggle();
```

after this:

```
$('#showResponse2').html('Toggle2: ' + link.prop('checked'));
```

hope this helps you

Comment: Where do we put these things?

Answer (score -1):

My solution :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //init jQuery DataTable
    $('#mainTabel').DataTable({
        'pageLength': 25,
        'columnDefs': [
            {
                'orderable': false,
                'targets': 7              
            },
            {
                className: '.hide',
                'visible': false
            }
        ],      
        // dom: 'Bfrtip',
        // buttons: [
        //     'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        // ],
        'language': {
                    'search': "_INPUT_",
                    'searchPlaceholder': 'Search...'
                    },
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': true,
      'searching'   : true,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : true,
      'autoWidth'   : true

    }); 
    $('#mainTabel').DataTable().columns('.hide').visible(false);


    //init botstrapToggle
    initToggle();
    $('#mainTabel_wrapper').click( function(){
        initToggle();
    });        
    $('#mainTabel_filter').keyup( function(){
        initToggle();
    });

    function initToggle(){ 
        $(function() {      
            $('.cb').find('input[type=checkbox][data-toggle=toggle]')
                                    .each(function(){
                $(this).bootstrapToggle();
            });
        });
    };
 });
```

[image: example]